# C# - format DataGridView date into messagebox

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, messagebox

I have a datagridview connected to a sql database and everything works fine.
I want to show the field "Date" (datetime on the database) formatted just as "dd/MM/yyyy" on a MessageBox.

I have it like this:

```
 MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
```

and it shows:

[image]

What can I add or edit in the code to remove the hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
string message = (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(message.Remove(10).ToString());
```

What this does is remove the last characters of the string, in this case the characters being the time

Answer (score 3):

Pass correct Date format i.e `"dd/MM/yyyy"` as a parameter to `ToString()`,

```
//As per your comment it seems type of ..Cells[4].Value is DateTime?
string dateValue =  dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ?? "No Date Found";
MessageBox.Show(dateValue);
```

---

Use correct format for Month,

```
mm - Prints minute (00 - 59)
MM - Prints month (00 - 12)
```

Comment: It returns me the error: "No overload for method ToString takes 1 arguments"

Comment: `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value` is it of type `DateTime?`? if yes then what you want to print if `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value` is null?

Comment: @MMelo31 I updated my answer to support `DateTime?` data type